# What does it mean when Traefik claims to be "natively compliant"?

Tags: traefik

I was going through the [traefik docs](https://docs.traefik.io/) and I saw:

> Traefik is **natively compliant** with every major cluster technology,
> such as Kubernetes, Docker, Docker Swarm, AWS, Mesos, Marathon, and
> the list goes on; and can handle many at the same time. (It even works
> for legacy software running on bare metal.)

What does being "natively compliant" mean in terms of a piece of software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a widely used term, but what it means in this particular context is that the application explicitly was coded to support those cloud technologies. In particular, libraries interfacing which each of that technologies were used in traefik code.

It is possible to make an appliation work, say in kubernetes, even if application itself is not aware of kubernetes. This is not the case with traefik, which uses api of docker, kubernetes, swarm, marathon, etc to support discovery. This is what they meant by "natively compliant" in this case, I beleive.